# How many devices can an IOS in-app purchase be restored?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

If I have an apple ID. can I use the same for twenty iPads? We have allowed in-app purchases in our application and we are afraid it may be abused by people sharing the same apple ID.

Do we as developers need to track the devices it is installed on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple require that purchases be restorable on every device that is associated with a common account and that the user be allowed to reinstall the software and restore the purchase on the same device as many times as they like.

In 99.99% of cases, iTunes accounts are linked to credit card details. People therefore tend not to share them. In theory you could use the same login on twenty iPads but you'd run the risk of whatever anti-fraud measures Apple have in place flagging up a potential card theft.

Adding additional tracking would put you in violation of the requirements of your contract with Apple, meaning that they'd probably pull your app if they found out. It's also technically very difficult — UDIDs are deprecated as of iOS 5 and anything you save as user data (such as a generated CFUUID) may be synced across devices, either by iCloud or by iTunes, and may alternatively not survive a deletion and reinstallation of your app.

Comment: Correct. The same rules applies to normal app downloading. Unlimited downloads on the same iTunes account.

Comment: Apple now limits the number of devices that have the same apple ID to 5.

Answer (score 9):

In-App-Purchases are bound to an user account, not a device.
You can't buy non-consumable products more than one time anyway.

From the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW11):

> Non-consumable products are purchased only once by a particular user. Once a non-consumable product is purchased, it is provided to all devices associated with that user’s iTunes account. Store Kit provides built-in support to restore non-consumable products on multiple devices.

---

Forget about the tiny percentage of people who share their account between 20 devices and use the time to improve your app for everybody else.